# Why won't my connection string work?

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

Could someone tell me why my connection string isn't working.. i'm currently using database first, but don't know why it wont connect. Whenever i try i get the error 
'The network path was not found'

connection string is:
    `<add name="FactsAndFiguresEntities1"        connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=SERVERNAME User Id=****; Password = **** catalog=FactsAndFigures;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: you may be missing a semi colon between SERVERNAME and User Id

Comment: What class is throwing that exception? WEre is your sql server, on another box... are you sure it is enabled for remote connections. Hard to answer this one without more info.

Comment: @MikeViscontini and password and catalog, I assumed those were just obfuscation typos.

Comment: How did you get this connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error network path not found, could refer to how you are referencing the metadata files. When you use "res://" EF tries to load the metadata from assemblies in the bin catalogue of the application. Do you have a bin catalogue?

Also I notice that you use both Integrated Security=True and Username/password. The system will use one or the other not both.

For details on EF connection strings see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756(v=vs.100).aspx